# quick-calc via emacsclient

Tags: calc

It's really handy to get stuff calculated in minibuffer using quick-calc (C-x * q) - I especially like that it automatically copies the result into buffer so it's just one C-y away.

Now the questions is - can I get all this goodness via emacsclient? Just printing out the results of calculating some string would be nice but having it in clipboard as well - even better.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want a way to call quick-calc from the command line if Emacs isn't even open yet?

Comment: No, emacs is running in daemon mode. I want to call quick-calc with emacsclient and immediately exit after result is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-e` option to just eval a lisp expression (from `man emacsclient`):

```
-e, --eval
       Do not visit files but instead evaluate the arguments as Emacs Lisp expressions.
```

E.g.

```sh
$ emacsclient -e '(calc-eval "solve(x^2 +x = 23, x)")'
"x = 4.3218"
```

I suppose that can be made easier via a shell function. E.g.

```sh
$ calc() { emacsclient -e "(calc-eval \"$@\")" | xargs; }
$ calc 'inv(
     [1, 2, 3, 4;
      6, 5, 4, 3;
      7, 12, 3, 4;
      5, 6, 3, 2])'
((-0.28571 0.71429 0.16667 -0.83333) (0.071429 -0.42857 1.1351e-14 0.5) (0.28571 -0.71429 -0.5 1.5) (0.071429 0.57143 0.33333 -1.1667))
```

I use the pipe through `xargs` here to get rid of the quotes (which implies passing the output as arguments to `echo`), which seems to work fine, but let me know if you see any adverse side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not really an answer but it did solved the overall problem for me: instead of trying to reach Emacs' calc via emacsclient from shell I've flipped the problem upside-down and started using eshell as my main shell which allows me to use "calc-eval EXPR" directly :)